# How to return a value from a async thread

Tags: java, android, executor

I am working on a `MediaPlayer` to play an audio file

Currently works on the main thread

```
 public boolean playFile(String path) {
    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioAttributes(AudioFocusManager.getPlaybackAttributes());
    try {
        mp.setDataSource(path);
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setOnErrorListener((mp1, what, extra) -> {
            return true;
        });
        mp.setOnCompletionListener( mp1 -> {
        });
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

but I am trying to move it to an executor

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(() -> {

    });
```

Once I move it to the executor, then the second and third returns triggers an error

> Unexpected return value

And `playFile` triggers the following

> Missing return statement

I have tried using `AtomicReference`

```
AtomicReference<Boolean> correctlyPlayed = new AtomicReference<>(false);
    //set up MediaPlayer
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    executor.execute(() -> {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setAudioAttributes(AudioFocusManager.getPlaybackAttributes());
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
            mp.setOnErrorListener((mp1, what, extra) -> {
                return true;
            });
            mp.setOnCompletionListener( mp1 -> {
            });
            correctlyPlayed.set(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AudioFocusManager.releaseAudioFocus();
            correctlyPlayed.set(false);
        }
    });

    return correctlyPlayed.get();
```

but it triggers always false, meaning that it does not wait for the thread to update it

How could I do it?

Comment: What is the exact exception when you run the second and third time? Can you post that exception and message? If it is simply "media file is in use" or something, then it is not a Java related problem. Let us clear that out first.

Comment: You should use `submit` instead of `execute`, as it returns a `Future`, with which you can manage the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment said, use `executor#submit` instead of `executor#execute`, so you can get a `Future`, and you can call `Future#get` to get the result:

```
       Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                // ...
                return true;
            }
        });
        return future.get(); // block until get result
```

Answer (score 1):

The execute method requires a Runnable and a Runnable does not return anything, that's why you get the unexpected return value error.
You can't get your playFile's return value from a separate thread directly like this, but your approach with the AtomicReference should work.
There is a built-in atomic type for boolean values, AtomicBoolean, consider using that instead.

Try changing this:

```
mp.setOnErrorListener((mp1, what, extra) -> {
    return true;
});
```

To this:

```
mp.setOnErrorListener((mp1, what, extra) -> {
    correctlyPlayed.set(true);
});
```

Also, you might want to synchronize your code to wait for the other thread to execute before returning, for that, consider checking out some semaphore synchronization techniques(e.g. CountdownLatch) and I suggest you to read up about the wait-notify mechanism too. The reason behind always getting false as a return value is most probably a synchronization issue, as you pointed out correctly.